# Floating number precision

Tags: python, floating-point

I started wondering why floating numbers sometimes behave in such a strange way. I found out that it is because a number has to be represented with either 32 or 64 bits, so at some point the number needs to be simplified and rounded up.

So I experimented a bit on Python to get a better idea of how floats behave:

`1-0.000000000000000001 == 1` returns `True` as expected.

However `0.000000000000000001 == 0` and `0.9999999999999999 == 1` return `False`.

Remarkably `1-0.000000000000000001 == 0.9999999999999999` also returns `False`

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Not necessarily an exact duplicate, but reading that post will likely answer your question.

Comment: Did you try the repeating 9s with one more 9?

Comment: Think about 1/3 presented with decimal notation. Here you have decimal value in binary notation. You can't store that if you have limited space.